Extending the defintion of Jordan inner measure in the 'obvious manner'?
Context:

Tao, in Introduction to Measure Theory, defines the Jordan inner measure of any $E$ bounded subset of $\mathbb R^d$ as,
$$m_{*,J}(E):=\sup\limits_{
  \substack{
   {A\subset E,\;\;} 
   {A\subset \mathbb R^d\text{ elementary set.}}}}\text{m}(A).$$
An elementary set in $\mathbb R^d$ is some union of finitely many boxes in $\mathbb R^d$ and a box in $\mathbb R^d$ is the product of $d$ many intervals of finite length.

The Lebesgue outer measure is defined as,
$$
{m^*(E)}:=\inf\limits_{
   E\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n,\\
   B_1,B_2,....\text{ boxes in }\mathbb R^d.}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|B_n|,
$$
where $|B_n|$ is the volume of the $n$-th box $B_n$. That is, it is the infimal cost needed to cover $E$ by a countable union of boxes in $\mathbb R^d$.

Let $B,B'$ be boxes in $\mathbb R^d$. We say, $B$, $B'$ are almost disjoint if the interior of $B$ is disjoint from the interior of $B'$.


I am trying to solve Exercise 1.2.5 which asks us to show that the Lebesgue outer measure of any countable union of almost disjoint boxes is its Jordan inner measure where “we extend the definition of Jordan inner measure to unbounded sets in the obvious manner”. I know that I need to use Lemma 1.2.9 (which says that the Lebesgue outer measure of countable union of almost disjoint boxes is sum of volume ie Jordan inner measure of the individual boxes).
Question 1: How to extend the Jordan inner measure to unbounded sets? At first, I thought that simply setting it to $+\infty$ would do (after all, this is what is done in the book when extending the Jordan outer measure to unbounded sets). But I also know that the following inequality holds for all bounded sets $E$,
$$m_{*,J}(E)\leq m^*(E)\leq m^*_{J}(E),$$
where $m^*_J(E)$ is the Jordan outer measure of $E$. So, if I want to have this inequality for unbounded $E\subset \mathbb R^d$, my initial choice of $+\infty$ may NOT work as for example, $m^*(\mathbb N)=0$ even though $m^*_J(E)=+\infty$.
Question 2: All this is going to lead to outer regularity theorem, ie that open sets can be expressed as countable union of almost disjoint boxes and for any $E\subset \mathbb R^d$,
$$m^*(E)=\inf_{E\subset U,\;U\subset \mathbb R^d\text{ open}}m^*(U).$$
I am NOT sure if we need to even consider the Jordan inner measure here. Instead of saying that $m^*(U)=m_{*,J}(U)$ (as $U$ is open and is hence countable union of almost disjoint boxes), wouldn't it be better to write,
$$m^*(U)=m^*(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}B_n)=\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}m^*(B_n)=\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}|B_n|,$$
using Lemma 1.2.9 and the result that Lebesgue outer measure of boxes is their volume?
In other words, once we have defined Lebesgue outer measure, do we still need to consider the Jordan inner and outer measures? I understand that they are mainly here for pedagogical reasons and I have greatly benefited from them though.

Q1: Ummm. $m_{,J}(\Bbb N) = 0, m^(\Bbb N) = 0, m^*_{J}(\Bbb N) = +\infty$ and $$0 \le 0 \le +\infty$$ so what is the problem here? Your counter example does not contradict the inequality at all.

Q2: In my experience, it is more common to develop Lebesgue measure without any reference to Jordan measure, so no, Jordan measure is not needed. I have not read Tao's book, so I cannot guess his purposes in bringing it up. But at the very least, it is appropriate to acknowledge Jordan's contribution to the whole theory.
